# Why do I need a return in a do while loop?

Tags: c, cs50

This was related to this code from a CS50x (Week 2) class.

The code was:

```
int get_negative_int(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Negative integer: ");
        printf("n is %i\n", n);
    }
    while (n < 0);
    return n;
}
```

I was confused why the "return n;" line is needed. Wouldn't the do while loop keep running while n < 0 and once n > 0 shouldn't it stop and pass the > 0 value of n to the int n without the "return n;" line?

I didn't have any errors but I was having trouble understanding how return works in this instance. I feel I'm missing something basic about how return works here and any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: `return n` doesn't change n.  It returns it's value to the caller.

Comment: `return n` isn't in the loop.

Comment: `return` exits the function and returns the value of `n` to the caller of the function. It does not affect the value of `n` in any way. Think of `return` as *go back to where you came from*, and the value after `return` is like *and take this with you*.

Comment: I'm actually confused by the `while (n < 0);`. *"Wouldn't the do while loop keep running while n < 0"* Yes. So it stops when `n >= 0` and returns that value. But why is this called `get_negative_int` when it actually returns a *positive* value? Note that it unconditionally *prints* the inputted numbers.

Comment: The CS50 actually seems to say "Let’s look at another buggy program: " and then this very code follows. We are supposed to find the problem by using a debugger, that's what the task is all about. Which is why @Bob__ is confused, they wrote a broken function on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to return a value from a function is via the `return` statement.

The do/while condition just controls the loop. Execution then continues at the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` has nothing to do with the loop. Any function returning a value such as `int get_negative_int(void)` returning an `int`, needs to have a `return` statement, simple as that.

The CS50 task is to figure out what's wrong with the function. Hint: it ain't the `return`.

> once n > 0 shouldn't it stop

Please note that the opposite of `n < 0` is `n >= 0`. The loop will indeed stop while a number 0 or larger is entered.